# Convert string of strings to string array in LabVIEW

Tags: arrays, string, labview

Is there a way to convert a string of strings to a string array in LabVIEW.

```
eg. "test hello yeh ok"
```

becomes

```
[0] = test
[1] = hello
[2] = yeh
[3] = ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working from memory here, so bear with me. Use the Convert from Spreadsheet String VI in the Strings palette. Set your delimiter as a space.

Comment: I tried that, but the resulting array is a 2d array of doubles

Comment: Figured it out, I had to set the data type to a space too

Comment: The data type input accepts any data, it's only the type that's important, so you could have wired e.g. an Empty String constant.

Answer (score 0):

[image: I have used Array Builder and later on Used Array Indexing Property to select and view the Item in a given Array]

I have used Array builder and also append to the already array with constant strings. and to view and locate to specific index I used the Array Index block.